# Can I have an internal webservice running in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to know if , with Azure, it supports the ability to have webservice running on a specific port which is accessible only by a Site running in Azure. E.g. I want to create a Website hosted on azure but I want some of the services to come from a webservice which I dont want consumer facing.

Is this possible with Azure , if so do I need multiple instances or can this be achieved with one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly do this.  Just create a role with an internal endpoint.

Comment: Can I have multiple services on a single instance with one having a role with an internal endpoint and another without?